# Importing package in another package's module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I am building a package (and then going to upload it on pypi). I have 3 modules in this package. These packages have a few dependencies like numpy, cv2, and more.

So, I mentioned my dependencies in the setup.py file.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='StyleTransferTensorFlow',
    url='https://github.com/LordHarsh/Neural_Style_Transfer',
    author='Hash Banka',
    author_email='harshbanka321@gmail.com',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),

    # Needed for dependencies
    install_requires=['matplotlib','tensorflow','os-win','ffmpy','glob2', 'pytest-shutil', 'pytube', 'opencv-python', 'pillow', 'numpy', 'tensorflow_hub'],
    
    version='0.0.8',
    # The license can be anything you like
    license='MIT',
    description="Package to apply style transfer on different frames of a video",
    # We will also need a readme eventually (there will be a warning)
    # long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

I have also imported them in the **init**.py file present in same directory as the modules.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
from pytube import YouTube
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import shutil
import glob
import ffmpy
```

But still i am getting error when I execute code in the module

```
NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
```

I am not sure why my imports are not running.
I have used cv2 inside a module to do the task.
So I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you `import cv2` from other modules besides `init.py`?

Comment: I am using google colab to work. When I directly use import command in colab it works. But the imports in the __init__.py doesn't work. What I want is that when when I use anything in package, it automatically import the required packages like cv2, numpy and others. So can you tell me where can I write my import commands. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you fully understand what `install_requires` and `packages` are for.

- `install_requires` specifies libraries that are *required* for your *installation* through `setup.py` to work. E.g. when installing it with `pip` or `python setup.py install`. You are specifying what should be on your computer *before* installing for the installation to work. No package will be installed: if a package listed here is missing, it will simply throw you an error during installation.
  A very common package to include there is `numpy`, as you may import it in the `setup.py`, for example if you have some C or FORTRAN code which needs to compile upon installation.
- `packages` argument shows which packages are needed for your *library* to work, so basically which packages to install along with the library. It will check if the package is not already installed on your machine, and if not install it along the library.

What I would do is empty entirely the `install_requires` argument. Don't even specify it if you are importing none of these packages in the `setup.py`. If it still doesn't work, I would replace `setuptools.find_packages()` with the list you are currently providing to `install_requires`.

Comment: PEP8 comment: your imports should be in alphabetical order.
Package organization comment: aren't you naming this `init.py` instead of `__init__.py`? Not sure if it's wanted or some misunderstanding.